# Automatic staging not working

Tags: git

I `touch newfile` in my working directory. I want to automatically stage and commit it by using `git commit -am "added newfile"`, which gives me nothing but the usual:

```
#Untracked files:
#newfile
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Git version: 1.8.4.msysgit.0

That should be working, shouldn't it?

Comment: Did you tried `git add .` ? a new file will not get staged but a change in an existing file will get staged with `git commit -am "added newfile"`

Comment: that's right, `git commit -a` only stages changes, not new files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`git commit` manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit):

> `-a`
>   `--all`
>
> Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, **but new files you have not told Git about are not affected.**

So regarding your question,

> That should be working, shouldn't it?

No, it shouldn't.

New files need to be `git add`ed manually first.

Comment: Ok, misunderstanding from my side. Thanks. Will be accepted in a few minutes.